# Does it make sense for "If $p$ and not p, therefore $q$" to be a valid argument?

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus

In propositional logic, an argument is invalid iff there is any instance where all the premises are true and the conclusion is false, if the set of premises is $$\left\{\:p,\:\neg p\:\right\}$$
then the argument is true for any conclusion $q$, this doesn't make sense in the real world (at least compared to other valid arguments), is there anything that sets this argument apart from other valid ones (that make sense to be valid)?

Comment: Yes it; see [Explosion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principle_of_explosion#Symbolic_representation). Apply the definition of [Valid argument](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Validity_(logic))

Comment: Glad that there is something special about it, thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Maybe the confusion comes from the fact that in the real world the assumptions $\{p, \neg p\}$ cannot both be true. A cat cannot be both alive and not alive. So this situation simply never occurs. It can occur in mathematics as part of a proof, or when the axiom system is inconsistent. The axiom system of the real world is consistent.

Comment: But we can change "Alice will go running no matter what." with "White holes exist." and the argument would still be valid, right?

Comment: I didn't read your question well. My answer should be more relevant now.

Comment: Yes it is, especially if we read the previous argument using an implication " If Alice does what he wanted to do and Alice doesn't do what he wanted to do then white holes exist" it doesn't say anything meaningful but it's valid (it wouldn't be natural to occur as you said anyway.)

Comment: Yes. My previous answer was about $\{p \implies q , (\neg p) \implies q \} \implies q$. Not about $\{p, \neg p\} \implies q$.

Comment: +1: but I am not sure that it makes any sense to talk about  "the axiom system of the real world". However, that is a question for philosophers not mathematicians. $\ddot{\smile}$.

Answer (score 2):

Assume otherwise. Then $\lnot((p\land \lnot p)\to q)$ holds, which is only true when  $p\land \lnot p$ is true while $q$ is false. But $p\land \lnot p$ is true exactly when both $p$ and $\lnot p$ are true, a contradiction. Thus $(p\land \lnot p)\to q$.

Answer (score 0):

A semantic entailment is valid when the conclusion is true in *all* interpritations where the premises are all true.

$q$ is false in no interpritation where $p$ and $\lnot p$ are both true (since there is none such).

Therefore it is valid to claim that $\{p, \lnot p\}$ entails $\{q\}$.